# Picture Library Slideshow Issue With Multiple Libraries

Tags: 2013, picture-library, image, slidelibrary

I have an extensive set of pictures on my SP13 enterprise wiki to display division capabilities.  The first one I added to a page worked great.  Then, I created the second picture library and tried to add that in another section of my page.

The library appears in the dropdown to select when I add the webpart, but the images from the first picture library I created appear in the slideshow.

Can you not have two slideshows rendering two different libraries on the same page?

Comment: Slideshow = Slides view? Interesting, when I add a webpart and switch it to "Slides" view, it doesn't show anything at all except of the webpart title after I save the page. Even with only one webpart on the page. Both wiki and normal pages... I use O365 SP2013 mode, so it should be the latest version I guess :)

Comment: I am having the same issue. I created a picture library slide show and it works great. I then add another webpart - picture library slide show, point it to another image library, but the images from the first slide show show up. I took a look at the article that was listed, but it only deals with image size. Did the original poster get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This has been a topic on the technet boards.  Take a look at this article.  It has a couple of answers, though I don't like either.  It appears to be a sizing issue with the underlying style sheets in SharePoint.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5ca65f7f-770b-4b0f-8e40-d08578a6442b/sharepoint-2013-picture-library-slideshow-web-part-image-not-displaying-correct-size

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around for this, its a bit messy but it does work

Lets say you have 2 Picture Libraries in the same site called **Photo1** and **Photo2**

You wish to display them on a page called MyPhotos.aspx

The process is as follows:

1. Create a file called HideEverything.css this contains styles to hide all the unwanted elements on a page, basically everything except the Slide Show. Upload this to a regular library.
2. Create a web part page called P1.aspx insert the Slideshow Web Part and connect it to **Photo1**. Add a content editor web part below this and Link it to HideEverything.css
3. Create a web part page called P2.aspx insert the Slideshow Web Part and connect it to **Photo2**. Add a content editor web part below this and Link it to HideEverything.css
4. Create a WIKI page called MyPhotos.aspx set the layout too two columns. In the left column insert a page viewer web part and set it to display *P1.aspx?IsDlg=2*, in the right column insert a page viewer web part and set it to display *P2.aspx?IsDlg=2*

Your slideshows will now display the correct content on MyPhotos.aspx

I have the styles for hiding the page elements if you need them